# ipa samba install failure socket did not correctly init

Tags: samba, kerberos

I am trying to setup a test environment to get `ipa` and `samba`.

I have two vms with the network setup and everything running.  I am trying to setup `ipa` and `samba` but I'm getting an error when trying to start `samba` service.

```
    Job for smb.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status smb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[root@main samba]# tail log.smbd 
[2017/01/23 23:16:23.606753,  0] ipa_sam.c:4193(bind_callback_cleanup)
  kerberos error: code=-1765328378, message=Client 'cifs/XXXX.XXXXXX.XXXXX@XXXXXXXX.XXXX' not found in Kerberos database
[2017/01/23 23:16:23.606833,  1] ../source3/lib/smbldap.c:1206(get_cached_ldap_connect)
  Connection to LDAP server failed for the 14 try!
[2017/01/23 23:16:24.606960,  1] ipa_sam.c:3711(ipasam_get_base_dn)
  Failed to get base DN from RootDSE: Timed out
[2017/01/23 23:16:24.607023,  0] ipa_sam.c:4505(pdb_init_ipasam)
  Failed to get base DN.
[2017/01/23 23:16:24.607068,  0] ../source3/passdb/pdb_interface.c:179(make_pdb_method_name)
  pdb backend ipasam:ldapi://%2fvar%2frun%2fslapd-XXXXXX-XXXX.socket did not correctly init (error was NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL)
```

I am able to log into the system and use test accounts with `ipa`.  I have raun the `ipa-adtrust-install` and followed the steps to get samba connected to ipa.  I think there is somehting with the kerberos configuration but I am unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue in the kerberos config inside the IPA server i have solved this issue by running ipa-server-upgrade.  Not exactly sure what i did in the setup to cause the issue but i needed to make this the kerberos authority.